# Tlmgr command not found after install Mac OS

Tags: pdftex, texlive, latexmk

I already looked up all the other questions, which were a bit similar to mine, but it did not help at all.

I just installed the Basic Tex for Mac and tlmgr and latexmk dont work. I also added it to my PATH. Maybe you see what I am doing wrong and could help me?

Mac OS: 10.14.3

**Error Message**

```
users-MBP-3:~ user$ tlmgr
-bash: tlmgr: command not found
users-MBP-3:~ user$
```

**My PATH**

[image]

Comment: Exactly where did you add this path change? And did you start a new terminal afterwards?

Comment: If you go to `/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-darwin`, can you find there `tlmgr`?

Comment: @NVaughan Yes I can see tlmgr in this folder.

Comment: @daleif I have changed it here: $HOME/.bash_profile

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` return? There should be no need to change the path. Did you use the BasicTeX installer package?

Comment: In a new terminal what does `echo $PATH`  give? And what about `which pdflatex`

Comment: @HerbSchulz Yes I used BasicTex

Comment: @daleif which pdflatex is showing nothing, just a new command line.

Comment: What about the other command? That which is not giving anything just shows that your path change is not in the right spot. Why I ask why you are using manually installed basic tex and not just the full mactex? The installer of which is taking care of all this.

Comment: @daleif is MacTex completely taking care of my paths? So I possibly could run my Latex in other editors commandline or VsCode?

Comment: You should probably install something like texmaker on your mac and see how it accesses latex. I don't use mac, the handling of the paths should be the same but I have no idea. I know that with mactex installed latex works on the command line. But this is not the same as editors being able to access it if the editor is started via a menu etc (Linux sometimes have the same problem, if you change the path in the wrong place). Thus editors like texmaker access larex in a different way, via a special prefix.

Comment: On that folder, what happens if you run, `./tlmgr --version`?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks everyone for helping me out! I just had a typo in my path, just as some of you had mentioned, that my path is not correct. Thats why it did not work.

This is the correct way to add a new path to the .bash_profile

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-darwin:"${PATH}"
```

alternatively if you have the 2022 version installed

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/universal-darwin:"${PATH}"
```

Comment: If you run `echo $PATH` what do you get? There should be `/Library/TeX/texbin` near the end of you PATH`. You shouldn’t need to add anything.

Comment: Wait! You say you installed BasicTeX but the path you show is not the one used by BasicTex2019 when installed by the BasicTeX installer package So, did you use the that .pkg or not?

Comment: update "/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/universal-darwin"